# sequelize migration file : adding createdAt and updatedAt columns

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

I have a sequelize V5 with nodeJS question.
I have a couple of models, User, Product and want to add createdAt and updatedAt columns to those tables in my MYSQL database.
Now I don't want to expose these fields to the consumer of the API (Front End application) but I want to populate these columns every time a record is created and updated.

Can somebody give me some advise?
Many Thanks,
Pete

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can add the timestamps property in the schema definition which will automatically add these fields and manage them whenever a record is created or updated.

```
 const model = sequelize.define('charity', {

    name: DataTypes.STRING,
    address: DataTypes.TEXT,
    contactPerson: DataTypes.STRING,
    phone: DataTypes.STRING,
    email: DataTypes.STRING,

}, {
    timestamps: true
});
```

Comment: Hello Waleed, thanks, this is for NodeJS with sequelize too?

Comment: Yes. It is for NodeJS with Sequelize.

Answer (score 2):

Just for those who are using migrations (instead of model sync) to create the tables, according to [official documentation](https://sequelize.org/v5/manual/models-definition.html#:%7E:text=using%20Sequelize%20migrations), we need to define the columns manually:

```
module.exports = {
  up(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    return queryInterface.createTable('my-table', {
      id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true,
      },

      // Timestamps
      createdAt: Sequelize.DATE,
      updatedAt: Sequelize.DATE,
    })
  },
  down(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    return queryInterface.dropTable('my-table');
  },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create dto's for user and product excluding createdAt and UpdatedAt